# R misreading of time from xlsx dataTable

Tags: r, excel, time

I have an issue very annoying.
I have some oxygen measurements saved in .xlsx table (created directly by the device software). Opened with excel, this is my part of my file. 
[image]

[image]
In the first picture, we can notice that sometimes, the software skips a second (11:13:00 then 13:02).
in the second picture, just notice the continuity of time from 11:19:01 to 11:19:09.
I call my excel table in R with the package readxl with the code

> oxy <- read_excel("./Metabolism/20180502 DAPH 20.xlsx" , 1)

And before any manipulation, when I check my table in R (Rstudio), I have that:
[image]

[image]

In the first case, R kept the time continuity by adding 11:13:01 and shift the next rows.
Then, later, reverse situation: the continuity of time was respected in excel, but R skips a second and again, shits the next rows.

At the end, there is the same number of rows. I guess it is a problem with the way R and excel round the time. But these little errors prevent me using the date to merge two tables, and the calculations afterwards are wrong.

May I do something to tell R to read the data exactly the same way Excel saved them?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Index both with a sequential integer counter each starting at the same point and use that for merging like with like. If you want the Excel version to be 'definitive' convert the index back to time with a lookup based on your Excel version.